# Laravel multi Auth returning JSON

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-middleware, laravel-authentication

I am trying to get laravel's multi auth setup. I already have a consumer login from my `consumers` table working. but now I need to set up the business login from the `businesses` table. (currently the business login is pulling data from the `consumers` table.

I am trying to get it to return JSON (JWT) vs Returning a login blade which I have found most of the info online has done.

**Businesses migration**

```
class CreateBusinessTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('businesses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('bus_id', 11);
            $table->string('bus_name', 50);
            $table->string('bus_address', 50);
            $table->string('bus_city', 50);
            $table->string('bus_prov', 50);
            $table->string('bus_postal', 50);
            $table->string('bus_phone', 50);
            $table->string('email', 50);
            $table->string('password', 20);
            $table->double('max_donatable', 10, 2);
            $table->integer('cashback_percent');
            $table->binary('bus_cover_photo'); 
            $table->binary('bus_profile_pic'); 
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->rememberToken(); 
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';   
        });
    }
```

**Business Model**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Contracts\JWTSubject;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Business extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject//Model
{
  use Notifiable;

  protected $table = 'businesses';
  protected $primaryKey = 'bus_id';
  protected $gaurd = 'business';

   protected $fillable = [ 'bus_id', 'bus_name', 'bus_address', 'bus_city', 'bus_prov', 'bus_postal', 'bus_phone', 'email', 'password', 'cashback_percent', 'bus_cover_photo', 'bus_profile_pic'];

   protected $hidden = [
      'password', 'remember_token',
  ];

  public function getJWTIdentifier()
 {
     return $this->getKey();
 }

 /**
  * Return a key value array, containing any custom claims to be added to the JWT.
  *
  * @return array
  */
 public function getJWTCustomClaims()
 {
     return [];
 }
}
```

**Business controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class businessAuthController extends Controller
{
 public function login()
 {
     $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
     if (! $token = /*auth()*/Auth::guard('business')->attempt($credentials)) {
         return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
     }

     return $this->respondWithToken($token);
 }
}
```

**Handler.php unauthenticated function**

```
   protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
   {
       if ($request->expectsJson()) {
           return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
       }
       $guard = array_get($exception->guards(), 0);
       switch ($guard) {
         case 'business':
           $login = 'business.login';
           break;
         default:
           $login = 'login';
           break;
       }
       return redirect()->guest(route($login));
   }
```

**Kernel.php**

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'business' => \App\Http\Middleware\Business::class,
    ];
}
```

**Providers**

```
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Consumer::class,
        ],
    'businesses' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Business::class,
           ],
    ],
```

**Gaurds**

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'business' => [
       'driver' => 'session',
       'provider' => 'businesses',
   ],
   'business-api' => [
       'driver' => 'jwt',
       'provider' => 'businesses',
   ],
],
```